# Compile POCO with UTF8 support

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, poco

I'm compiling POCO 1.5 version with

```
#define POCO_WIN32_UTF8
```

in Config.h. As I can read in docs, with this flag I'm enabling UTF8 support, but when I go to File_WIN32.cpp I can see how in createFileImpl() there is one call to CreateFileA() function (win ascii version of this function) not call to CreateFileW(). Where I am wrong? Any other flag to activate?

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking in File_WIN32U.cpp for the Unicode implementation. File_WIN32U.h is the header.